# Wrapping script tag in function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get this function working. I'm trying to get it to execute the function to read the xml only when li is clicked

The following is my jQuery:

```
     <script>
                $("ul.productcat li").on('click', function (e) {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        // Class of the one to be shown
                        subclazz = $this.data("class"); 
                        $('article > div').removeClass('show');
                        $('.' + subclazz).addClass('show');                  
                    mygallery(subclazz);
                });
            </script> 
            function mygallery(config){ 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/jquery.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/swfobject.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/flashgallery.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/gallery.swf', 'gallery/'+config+'.xml', { width: '650px', height: '600px', background: 'transparent' });
            </script>
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `mygallery` function code is terrible... You mixed up HTML with JS.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery before loading jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be doing something like:

```
//load all the scripts
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/swfobject.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/flashgallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.productcat li").on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
        // Class of the one to be shown
        subclazz = $this.data("class");                   
        mygallery(subclazz);
    });
});
function mygallery( config ) {
    jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/gallery.swf', 'gallery/'+config+'.xml', { 
         width: '650px', 
         height: '600px', 
         background: 'transparent' 
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function mygallery(config){ 
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/swfobject.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/js/flashgallery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/gallery.swf', 'gallery/'+config+'.xml', { width: '650px', height: '600px', background: 'transparent' });
        </script>
}
```

change in

```
 function mygallery(config){  
jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/gallery.swf', 'gallery/'+config+'.xml',
 { width: '650px',
 height: '600px',
 background: 'transparent'
 }
);
}
```